# Is there a way to persist authentication from one web app to another, nested web app in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, authentication, iis-7

So my company has an ASP.NET web app, targeting .NET 3.5. I am tasked with building a ticketing system for them. I don't really need to use any resources of the company app, except for authentication. I would like to target .NET 4.0 and use the 4.0 goodies like entity framework and mvc 3.0. If I create an application targeting .net 4 nested within the main web app in IIS, is there a way to persist authentication so they do not require a different session within the 4.0 web app?

Please let me know if I am being unclear.

Thank you.

Comment: May want to see my [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961291/cross-site-authentication-options-on-separate-domains/4961360#4961360) answering something similar to this.

Comment: what authentication mechanism are you using? Membership?

Comment: @brokenglass Yes. I believe so. I have access to User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in the main app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use membership authentication you can share sessions between different web applications provided the following is true:

1. All of them share the same machine
   key - you can set the `machineKey`
   explicitly in each web.config to the
   same value.
2. You are using the same
   authentication cookie name (i.e.
   `.ASPXAUTH` by default)

There might be other ways, but this is how I got it to work.

Also see this article for reference: [Forms Authentication Across Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx)

Comment: Nice! This should do it. I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

If the subfolder in the main IIS application is not an application itself, it will be loaded into the AppDomain of the parent IIS application, and this would ensure that session state is shared between the applications. If it is its own IIS application, it will have its own AppDomain and be a separate running application.

If it shares the same AppDomain as the parent IIS application, you have to be careful of where you deploy your binaries. If you do not add in a private bin path for assembly resolution, all assemblies must be located in the root `/bin`. But this has the additional risk of the main app looking for assemblies in your additional subfolder where it shouldn't be looking.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah see it needs to be it's own application so I can target .NET 4.0. I can't use the parent web app because they are not targeting .net 4.0

Comment: Is it possible to add it as another site and run it off another port?